# How to make my docker webserver in AWS host available in public internet?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, sockets, docker, tcp

I have a running apache webserver in centos docker container which is hosted by AWS redhat instance.

I am able to curl my container webserver in AWS instance local host but unable to access publicly in my laptop web browser.

details of the Webserver:

```
docker run -d --name httpd -p 8080:8080 -v /home/ec2-user/apache/web1/www:/var/www:Z docker.io/centos/httpd-24-centos7
```

The output of `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
abd790b28b51        docker.io/centos/httpd-24-centos7   "container-entrypo..."   2 hours ago         Up 20 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 8443/tcp   httpd
```

In AWS instance :

`curl http://localhost:8080`

Hello World!!!

But unable to get this in public internet using AWS host public ip from my laptop.

The output of `netstat -tulpn`:

```
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                -
```

My AWS Security inbound rules:

```
HTTP    TCP 80  157.51.138.196/32
All traffic All All 157.51.138.196/32
SSH TCP 22  157.51.138.196/32
DNS (TCP)   TCP 53  157.51.138.196/32
HTTPS   TCP 443 157.51.138.196/32
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but is there no inbound rule for port 8080?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing inbound rule 8080 on instance security group add it and check and inform further if not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray it Worked!!!

But not sure how it worked actually ;-) Will try to find out that...

I just stopped all apache containers and removed them entirely. Then executed the below command and everything worked perfect.

While using the below make sure you are mapping the volume (-v) correctly to the index.html file in your host.

```
docker run -d --name httpd -p 9080:8080 -v /home/ec2-user/apache/web1/www/html:/var/www/html:Z docker.io/centos/httpd-24-centos7
```